# How to reload images by class name - Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript

How can I reload images that have a same class name ?

I tried this but it doesn't refresh the images:

```
<img class="refresh" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/bulbon.gif"></img>
<img class="refresh" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png"></img>

// javascript: //
a=document.getElementsByClassName(refresh);
for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++)a[c].src=a[c].src;
```

Hope the question is clear

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by "refreshing" the images? Browsers cache resources.

Comment: @FelixKling I have a project for rain and dust.. ect, maps and it refresh every 5 mins

Comment: Maybe append a random parameter to the URL to force refetching?

Comment: @FelixKling okay how to do that with just class name? thank you

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with class names, you just need a reference to the DOM element. `getElementsByClassName` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh your image by replacing the src with url parameter like this.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.refresh');
    if (imgs) {

      for (var i = 0, length = imgs.length; i < length; i++) {
        var pt = /\?v=.+/g;
        if (imgs[i].src) {
          pt.test(imgs[i].src) 
          ? imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace(pt, "?v=" + Date.now()) 
          : imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src + "?v=" + Date.now();
        }
      }

    }
  }, 1000 * 60 * 5);

};
```

```html
<img class="refresh" src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/bulbon.gif"></img>
<img class="refresh" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png"></img>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Also this appends to the URL on each click: `http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png?v=1477615789834?v=1477615790233?v=1477615791337?v=1477615794537`. You might want to use `this.getAttribute('src')` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling Im sorry. Ill fix it. Thaks

Comment: Thank you very good please edit it to auto refresh the images every 5 mins

Comment: @anmml So how should its start.. when you click on the image or within the window onload?

Comment: @DININDU  window onload and auto refresh every 5 mins without click

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('refresh');
for (var c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
    var n = a[c].src.indexOf("?"); if (n == -1) {n = a[c].src.length;}
    a[c].src = a[c].src.substring(0, n)+"?n="+Date.now();
}
```